# How do I staple faced insulation to ceiling joists if the flange has been cut off for narrower spaces?

Tags: insulation

I'm insulating a detached home office/shed. For the ceiling, the rafters are 24in on center so I got 22" faced insulation for that. However on the ends of the structure, the rafters are only 21in on center so I have to rip the insulation to fit. This means the little paper flange for stapling will be cut off. How do I staple that side to the rafters then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
Cut the fiberglass but not the paper. You could do this by pulling the fiberglass off the paper, sliding a protective sheet under, then cutting the fiberglass.

**Option 2**
Cut the batt, then add adhesive tape as a flange. Use fiber-reinforced paper packing tape or something similar that won't easily tear when you staple it.

**Option 3**
Use unfaced batts there and then add poly sheeting. Reduce waste by cutting the batts to 19-1/2" in length (a bit more so they're snug) and running them crosswise.